# Android, What is the difference between neenbedankt A.P and Support Annotation?

Tags: android, annotation-processing

Recently I replaced `neenbedankt` annotation processing library with google `Support-Annotation` library, and change all `apt` methods in `build.gradle` with `annotationProcessor` and every thing works good, My question is what is the difference between them and when should we use each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. `annotationProcessor` is the new feature of gradle plugin.

More info from the creator of `android-apt` [here](http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Whats-next-for-android-apt/)

The main conclusion from this article is that `annotationProcessor` is doing the same as `android-apt` and that is why `android-apt` is no longer maintained. You are advised to use `annotationProcessor`

Comment: So if both of them are the same, why `neen` has plugin but the `support` one doesn't ?

Comment: `android-apt` is a plugin to gradle android plugin, that is why it needs to be added to classpath. `annotationProcessor` is now part of gradle android plugin, it does not need anything to be added to classpath.